# Разделение строки Arduino

Tags: парсер, ide, arduino

Есть строка в формате login:pass, как запихнуть login в одну переменную, а pass в другую? Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: работаю в Arduino IDE

Comment: раз «работаете в ide», то и впишите то, что требуется, в те поля ввода, где требуется. а если всё-таки не «работаете в ide», а **пишете программу** (на каком-то языке программирования), то эту информацию надо внести в текст вопроса (нажав [edit]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как обычно.

```
char pLoginPass[];

char* pLogin;
char* pPassword;

pLogin = pLoginPass;
pPassword = pLogin;    
while( *pPassword != ':' )
   ++pPassword;
*pPassword = 0;
++pPassword;
// Чунга-чанга.
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, язык программирования Arduino - C++.
Нагуглил код по этой же проблеме:

```
string str("Строка, которую нужно разбить.");
string separ("разделитель");
string::size_type pos = str.find(separ); // Позиция первого символа строки-разделителя.
string::size_type pos = str.find(separ); // Позиция первого символа строки-разделителя.
string first = str.substr(0, pos); // Строка до разделителя.
string second = str.substr(pos+separ.length()); // Строка после разделителя.
```

[Источник](http://programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=15988&highlight=%F0%E0%E7%E1%E8%F2%FC%20%F1%F2%F0%EE%EA%F3)

Comment: Спасибо, пригодиться.